# Using Messge for a file.choose prompt

Tags: r, prompt

If I paste a simple prompt into R for choosing a file like this:

```
message("Choose X")
X<-file.choose()
message("Choose Y")
Y<-file.choose()
```

Everything works fine. I get a message asking me to choose X along with a file choose window.

But if I source this same code:

```
source("Choose.R")
```

The file choose window opens first, with the message only showing up after the file has been chosen. If I have several of these in a row in the middle of a long bit of code, things get confusing quickly. I can use "readline" as a prompt  as opposed to "message" to avoid this confusion. But I'd prefer to use "message".

Comment: Does `source("Choose.R", echo = TRUE)` help at all?

Comment: Are you running via RGui on windows?

Comment: Running base R console on a Mac

Comment: See also `choose.files`, it has a `caption` argument that shows in the open file dialog.

Comment: Yes- Running echo=TRUE does cause the commands to run in order.